# Index ot of range with numba.guvectorize

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, numba

I' trying to compile a function with `numba.guvectorize` but runs in to a index out of range exception

```
def compute_kinetic_energy(velocity, mass, ke):
    ke = 0.0

    # Increase kinetic energy
    for i in prange(velocity.shape[0]):
        for x in range(2):
            ke += velocity[i, x] * velocity[i, x] * mass[i]
```

The above function works perfect until I try to do the guvectorization:

```
compute_kinetic_energy_gu = guvectorize(['float32[:,:], float32[:], float32'],
                             '(nnodes,dim),(nnodes),()->()',
                             target='cpu',
                             nopython=True)(compute_kinetic_energy)
```

The code for execution:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize, prange

nnodes = 1000
mass = np.ones(nnodes, dtype=np.float32)
velocity = np.zeros(nnodes*3, dtype=np.float32).reshape(nnodes,3)

compute_kinetic_energy(velocity, mass, ke)      # Works :)
compute_kinetic_energy_gu(velocity, mass, ke)   # Do not work :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake. I hade the wrong signature for the function. Correct call is

```
compute_kinetic_energy_gu = guvectorize(['float32[:,:], float32[:], float32'],
                     '(nnodes,dim),(nnodes)->()',
                     target='cpu',
                     nopython=True)(compute_kinetic_energy)
```